# device compatabiltiy for iphone4,iphone5,iphone6 and iphone 6+

Tags: iphone, xcode-storyboard

how to design a ui in storyboards for all iphone device compatable

i'm not able to design for iphone 4 while using iphone5 in stoeyboards

Problem

is coming with images and height of devices how can i do that

any suggestions or links for tutorials

i searched and tried everywhere but no use in implementation

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5wD8dvSDbM please watch this u get an idea

Comment: have you seen the image assets ?

Comment: i'm new to ios and objective c  and i'm having no idea about how to use auotlayout constraints and how to set image assets

Comment: watch the above video and do as per the following...

Answer (score 0):

with the use of auto layout you can achieve your goal. Please make sure you have a better understanding on how to use auto layout.

You can also see videos on auto layout. additionally you can preview your storyboard for all devices.

please me know.

Comment: i'm having trouble with images and less height in iphone5 and iphone4 could u give me any direction for that

Answer (score 0):

Add as per the resolution

**Right click** on any of your file and **Add new** then select the image select in the **assets** then add as per your need and resolution.

[image]